# Find the distribiution function of the random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Assume that $ \Omega =[0,2] $ and  P is geometrical probability on $ \Omega $. Find the distribution function of the random variable defined as:
$$ X(\omega) = \omega, 0 \leq \omega  \lt 1$$
$$ X(\omega) = \omega-1, 1 \leq \omega  \leq 2$$

So

$t = \omega$

$t = \omega-1$  => $\omega = t+1$

[image]

I know that the answer is

$$ F_x(t) = 0, t<0$$
$$ F_x(t) = 1, t \geq1$$,
but I'm not sure how it should be for $$ 0\leq t \lt 1$$

Comment: Can you elaborate on what $P$ means? What is a geometrical probability?

Comment: As far as I understand I need to calculate the probability of "being inside" the area given by a function depending on t. http://www.chegg.com/homework-help/definitions/geometric-probability-63

Comment: So say you take a random sample from your sample space $[0,2]$ using $P$. What does that look like? Does it mean you are equally likely to select any of the numbers between $0$ and $2$? I'm not sure you have provided enough information to answer the question.

Comment: Probably yes, that's the whole question as I got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase "$P$ is a geometrical distribution on $\Omega = [0,2]$" seems to be non-standard terminology. Under the interpretation that $P$ is the uniform distribution on $\Omega$, it's pdf can be written $p(\omega) = 1/2$ for $\omega \in \Omega$, i.e. $P(\omega \lt t) = \frac{1}{2}t$ for all $t \in [0,2]$.

Fix $t \in [0, 1]$

$$P(X(\omega) < t) = P(X(\omega) < t \ |\  \omega \in [0,1))P(\omega \in [0,1)) +  P(X(\omega) < t \ |\  \omega \in [1,2))P(\omega \in [1,2))$$
$$ = P(X(\omega) < t \ |\  \omega \in [0,1))\frac{1}{2} +  P(X(\omega) < t \ |\  \omega \in [1,2))\frac{1}{2}$$

And using the definition of $X$,

$$ = P(\omega < t \ |\  \omega \in [0,1))\frac{1}{2} +  P(\omega - 1 < t \ |\  \omega \in [1,2))\frac{1}{2}$$

$$ = t\frac{1}{2} +  t\frac{1}{2} = t$$